# GIT : Search for all directories containing lower case names

Tags: git

Iam using GIT on windows. How can i search for directories in a repository across all commits containing lower case directory name? Example i have the following files

- Test1\MyDirectory\Testfile.txt
- test2\mydirectory\Testfile.txt
- Test3\mydirectory\Testfile.txt
- test4\mydirectory\Testfile.txt
- test5\mydirectory\Testfile.txt

The search should return the following result.

- test2\mydirectory\Testfile.txt
- test4\mydirectory\Testfile.txt
- test5\mydirectory\Testfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can tell git to ignore case mismatches:

1. `git config --global core.ignorecase true` (to set it globally)
2. `git config core.ignorecase true` (for a particular repository)

Comment: Thanks Burhan...one more question...how can i get the list of all directories in my GIT repository having lower case names across all commits?

Comment: Iam very new to GIT. So, didn't quite get your solution. Iam using GIT for windows and not msysgit. Can you provide me with a sample syntax for searching through a complete branch across all commits for the list of directories having lower case names?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/158473) might be useful to detect all paths identical except for their case:

> You can do:

```
git ls-files | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -d
```

> but:
>
> 1. It will print only the lowercased version, not all versions.
> 2. It doesn't handle filenames with embedded newlines.
>
> You could fix both with something like:

```
  git ls-files -z | perl -0ne '
    push @{$h{lc($_)}}, $_;
    END {
      print join("\n", @{$h{$_}}) . "\n\n"
        foreach grep { @{$h{$_}} > 1 } keys(%h);
    }
  '
```

The rest of the thread discusses the merit of `git ls-files` (which can be slow) vs.  `git ls-tree -r <commit>`.